# Permissions to create sandbox or developer org

Tags: sandbox, developer-edition

I don't have the option to create a sandbox and here is my question below.
Who can create a Developer org or a Sandbox org?

Comment: Hi Mary, welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to give your questions a specific title, and remember that this is a community knowledge base (not Salesforce Support). I'll edit your question to clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can create a developer Org by signing up for it and requesting.  It is not connected to your Production org in anyway and is a base default org meant for development and testing.

Creating a Sandbox is depending on what sort of Org you have as defined here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5

You can also purchase additional Sandboxes beyond what your Org is setup as.